# Transparent node with opaque text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a simple way to create a transparent node with opaque text? Preferably without having to use a postaction or redraw the node.

In the example below I'd like to achieve the effect of the first three nodes, without redrawing the second node to create the opaque text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % desired effect:
    \node [fill=red,circle,minimum size=6mm,inner sep=0mm] {};
    \node [right,fill=green,opacity=.2] {Node};
    \node [right] {Node};

    % undesired effect:
    \node at(2,0) [fill=red,circle,minimum size=6mm,inner sep=0mm] {};
    \node at(2,0) [right,fill=green,opacity=.2] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

After setting the `opacity`, you have to reset the `text opacity=1` to get opaque text. The `opacity` key is a shorthand for setting the `draw opacity` and the `fill opacity` at the same time, and the `fill opacity` in turn automatically applies to the `text opacity`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % undesired effect:
    \node at(2,0) [fill=red,circle,minimum size=6mm,inner sep=0mm] {};
    \node at(2,0) [right,fill=green,opacity=.2,text opacity=1] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```