# Layer between a node and its text

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-matrix

My question is similar to [Transparent node with opaque text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42401/transparent-node-with-opaque-text) .
The difference is that i want the red circle to be above the green rectangle and below the word  "Node". And also I do not want to draw the node twice.

(the image is from the other question, what i want to achieve is similar to the first image)
[image: example]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % desired effect:
    \node [right,fill=green] {Node};
    \node [fill=red,circle,minimum size=6mm,inner sep=0mm] {};
    \node [right] {Node};

    % undesired effect:
    \node at(2,0) [right,fill=green] {Node};
    \node at(2,0) [fill=red,circle,minimum size=6mm,inner sep=0mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think I am looking for a layer between a node and its text.

(Sorry if it should have not been posted as a separate question, I was uncertain).

Here is a longer MWE showing what i want to achieve finally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}


\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{999999}

\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}
\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}

\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {draw=#1,fill=#1!50,rounded corners,line width=2pt}}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{color2} m m}{
\draw[myfillcolor=#1] ([shift={(.1cm,-.1cm)}]#2.north west)rectangle ([shift={(-.1cm,.1cm)}]#3.south east);
}


\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={inner sep=0,text centered,opacity=.5,text opacity=1},
    every even row/.style={nodes={
                rectangle,
                draw,
                minimum size=0.8cm,
                fill=color1,
                font=\Large,
                text height=2ex,
                text depth=.25ex,
                text centered,
                }},
        column 10/.style={nodes={text width=1cm}},
        row 1/.style={minimum height=0.5cm},
        row 5/.style={minimum height=0.5cm}
    ]
    (m)
{
    \& x\& x\&\&\\
    |[fill=none,fill=color1!50, dashed]|~\&x\&x\&x\&x\\
    |[text height=0.2cm]|~\\
    |[draw=none,fill=none]|$x:$\&x\&x\&x\&x\\
    \& x\&\&\&\\
};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
\only<2>{\fhighlight[color2]{m-2-2}{m-4-5}}
\only<3>{\fhighlight[color3]{m-2-1}{m-4-4}}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the example, i want the red and green rectangles NOT to be transparent or opaque, but instead bright, and to be placed over the gray boxes but under the text

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: That's not going to be easy... Could you specify what exactly your requirement of "not drawing the node twice" entails? Would it be okay to draw the rectangle and the text separately? Or do you want a single command that creates both the rectangle and the text? Also, I think it might be a good idea if you could explain why you need this functionality. Maybe there's a more straightforward way to handle the situation.

Comment: In addition to @Jake 's comment, how far should the transparent fill go in the background? For example, if all is drawn over a blue background, should that blue rectangle be at the same layer with red circle or behind the node's transparent filling?

Comment: I'm preparing a beamer presentation, with some nodes in a matrix that have each different shapes (some are square and gray, others simply show text without shape or color). I want to highlight, in the same slide and different times (using overlays), different portions of the matrix (see for example the last answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix). However, if i place the highliting in the front layer, the node text is "grayed out", while if i place it in the back layer, the highlighting is grayed out by the nodes. I want it to be in the middle.

Comment: That would be qite difficult since the highlight is another tikz picture and will have no access to previous pictures' layers (or I don't know how). One option might be to attack it via `ocg` tools but it looks like drawing the node twice is much less work. If the highlighting is in the same picture then it's maybe easier to draw the highlight twice but again three layer solution would need to draw the different parts of the node separately.

Comment: @percusse the highlight is in the same picture. Is it possible to "switch off" a layer using overlays? This could be a solution since i could prepare different layers for the highlithings and then "switch them on and off" as needed.

Comment: Have a look at this answer : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65096/how-to-make-a-diagram-composed-of-superimposed-layers-where-the-viewer-can-make

Comment: @percusse the package does more than what i want to achieve: i do not need any extra switches, and will use the keyboard to go from one slide to the following in a linear way. But I will look moee into it and see if I let it work for me. (also I will have to learn how to install it under MiKTeX)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Qrrbrbirlbel answer is very nice, but I think one could also proceed without saving the text. The trick is very simple: use at least three layers, `myback`, `highlight` and `main`; in the `main` layer there will be the text of the matrix, in the `myback` layer the matrix fill and in the `highlight` layer... the `highlighting`. What is important here, is that the `highlight` layer should be declared behind the main (text) but before the matrix fill (myback). Thus, with this approach, one should declare a posteriori how the matrix is filled and this is the only disadvantage I see.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}

\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{999999}

\pgfdeclarelayer{myback} % layer to fill the matrix
\pgfdeclarelayer{highlight} % layer to highlight the matrix
\pgfsetlayers{myback,highlight,main}

\tikzset{my fill color/.style = {draw=#1,fill=#1!50,rounded corners,line width=2pt}}

\begin{document}

% For both commands the second argument could be used to select the layer: here
% is not really necessary since the default is required, but having this option may help
% for other purposes (I still have to think about them..)

\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{color2} O{highlight} m m}{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{#2}
\draw[my fill color=#1] ([shift={(.1cm,-.1cm)}]#3.north west)rectangle ([shift={(-.1cm,.1cm)}]#4.south east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bhighlight}{O{black} O{myback} m m}{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{#2}
\draw[#1] (#3.north west)rectangle (#4.south east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={inner sep=0,text centered},
    every even row/.style={nodes={
                minimum size=0.8cm,
                %fill=color1,
                font=\Large,
                text height=2ex,
                text depth=.25ex,
                text centered,
                }},
        column 10/.style={nodes={text width=1cm}},
        row 1/.style={minimum height=0.5cm},
        row 5/.style={minimum height=0.5cm}
    ] (m) {
    \& x\& x\&\&\\
    ~\&x\&x\&x\&x\\
    |[text height=0.2cm]|~\\
   $x:$\&x\&x\&x\&x\\
    \& x\&\&\&\\
    };

% the matrix fill always visible: put in last layer, myback

\bhighlight[fill=color1!50, dashed, opacity=0.5]{m-2-1}{m-2-1}

\foreach \i in {2,...,5}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\x{\i}
\bhighlight[draw,rectangle, opacity=0.5]{m-2-\x}{m-2-\x}
}

\foreach \i in {2,...,5}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\x{\i}
\bhighlight[draw,rectangle, opacity=0.5]{m-4-\x}{m-4-\x}
}

% matrix highlighting

\only<2>{\fhighlight[color2]{m-2-2}{m-4-5}}
\only<3>{\fhighlight[color3]{m-2-1}{m-4-4}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Not that big of a disadvantages: I like the clarity as one can specify precisely which nodes are using what style. The fact that cells inherit styles of their row/column cost me a lot of time in finding a solution myself …

Comment: Yes, I agree that setting the styles after having drawn the matrix is much more clear (also because I don't like too much redefine styles locally inside the matrix: I prefer having just matrix of text, or at maximum with some `\tikzmark`s). It would be great, but I think is not so simple, define some `background column/row` style that apply the styles on the `background` layer directly: that will do the trick almost straightforward.

Answer (score 10):

*The old and*  too localized *solution where I defined an extra shape can be found in [the history of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/87165/6).*

---

I can’t see a solution without re-using parts of the matrix.

Ideas:

1. Drawing and filling the rectangle shape on a background layer, similar to [Cut one side of a rectangle node in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82279/16595), didn’t work: Apparently `\tikzlastnode` (or `\tikzmatrixname-\tikzmatrixcurrentrow-\tikzmatriccurrentcolumn`) and `pgfonlayer` don’t play nice and mess within `append after command`.

   But, similar to solution 3, saving the draw and fill options for later use does work. Unfortunately, this deals differently with options that are given to `every even row` and the local `|[<options>]|` which is the reason why `opacity=.5` and `draw` have to be given to the `m-2-1` again, but this can be made easier with a style that is given to `every even row` and as well to the local options.

   The `back` style re-uses its argument (`#1`) with the option `opacity=0`; this serves the purpose of not changing the actual dimension of the nodes.
2. Re-drawing the whole matrix where only the text is being typeset, realized be redefining PGF’s `\pgfusepath` or overwriting the `fill` and the `draw` style, so that one can just re-use the same `\matrix` call.

   This is the easiest solution, but re-draws the node’s content, therefore not usable when `text opacity` is applied.
3. Saving the node’s text and typeset it again.

   - Unfortunatly, I couldn’t find a way to grab the node’s content and save it as plain text. (Reference: [Using execute at begin node with \phantom and \pgfuseimage in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59753/16595), [Use node text as argument for a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18518/16595))

     Maybe there is a solution that uses a [few named saveboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73120/savebox-equivalent-of-csname) and the `lrbox` environment.
   - That is the reason I defined a `back` style that takes the node’s content, typesets it inside a `\phantom` and saves it later with the node’s name to draw it on top of all (can be used inside a `pgflayer`, too, of course.

### Code 1

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse,etoolbox,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}

\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,1,0}\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{999999}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}

\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {draw=#1,fill=#1!50,rounded corners,line width=2pt}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{color2} m m}{
    \draw[myfillcolor=#1] ([shift={(.1cm,-.1cm)}]#2.north west)rectangle ([shift={(-.1cm,.1cm)}]#3.south east);
}

\def\backgroundtodrawlater{}
\newcommand*{\saveMe}[1]{%
    \ifcsname iph\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname
        \StrCount{\backgroundtodrawlater}{,}[\kommaCount]%
        \StrBefore[\kommaCount]{\backgroundtodrawlater}{,}[\backgroundtodrawlater]
    \fi
    \ifx\backgroundtodrawlater\empty%
        \xappto\backgroundtodrawlater{{#1}/\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}%
    \else%
        \xappto\backgroundtodrawlater{,{#1}/\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname iph\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname{}%
}
\newcommand*{\drawMyBackBoxes}{%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
    \foreach \opt/\name in \backgroundtodrawlater {
        \expandafter\ifx\csname iph\name\endcsname\empty
%           \typeout{opt="\opt", name="\name"}% debug
            \expandafter\path\expandafter[\opt] (\name.south west) rectangle (\name.north east);
            \expandafter\xdef\csname iph\name\endcsname{ }
        \else
            \expandafter\xdef\csname iph\name\endcsname{}
        \fi
    }
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
\tikzset{
    back/.style={
        #1,
        opacity=0,
        save path={#1},
    },
    save path/.code={\saveMe{#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={inner sep=0pt,text centered,opacity=.5,text opacity=1},
    every even row/.style={nodes={
            rectangle,
            back={
                draw,
                fill=color1,
                opacity=.5
            },
            minimum size=0.8cm,
            font=\Large,
            text height=2ex,
            text depth=.25ex,
            text centered,
            text opacity=1,
    }},
    column 10/.style={nodes={text width=1cm}},
    row 1/.style={minimum height=0.5cm},
    row 5/.style={minimum height=0.5cm}
] (m) {
                                                  \& x \& x \&   \&   \\
        |[back={fill=color1!50, draw, dashed}]| ~ \& x \& x \& x \& x \\
        |[text height=0.2cm]|      ~                                  \\
        |[back={draw=none,fill=none}]| $x:$       \& x \& x \& x \& x \\
                                                  \& x \&   \&   \&   \\
    };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \only<2>{\fhighlight[color2]{m-2-2}{m-4-5}}
    \only<3>{\fhighlight[color3]{m-2-1}{m-4-4}}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\drawMyBackBoxes
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Code 2

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,1,0}\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{999999}
\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {draw=#1,fill=#1!50,rounded corners,line width=2pt}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{color2} m m}{\draw[myfillcolor=#1] ([shift={(.1cm,-.1cm)}]#2.north west)rectangle ([shift={(-.1cm,.1cm)}]#3.south east);}
\newcommand{\repeatMeText}[1]{
    #1%
    \def\repeatMe{{% note the extra pair of braces, keeps changes local!
%       \renewcommand{\pgfusepath}[1]{}% either this
        \tikzset{
            fill/.style={},% or this and
            draw/.style={},% this
            column sep=\pgflinewidth,% compensates for missing "draw"
            row sep=.5\pgflinewidth% compensates for missing "draw"
            }
        #1
    }}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\repeatMeText{
\matrix [
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={inner sep=0,text centered,opacity=.5,text opacity=1},
    every even row/.style={nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw,
            minimum size=0.8cm,
            fill=color1,
            font=\Large,
            text height=2ex,
            text depth=.25ex,
            text centered,
    }},
    column 10/.style={nodes={text width=1cm}},
    row 1/.style={minimum height=0.5cm},
    row 5/.style={minimum height=0.5cm}
] (m) {
                                     \& x \& x \&   \&   \\
        |[fill=color1!50, dashed]|~  \& x \& x \& x \& x \\
        |[text height=0.2cm]| ~                          \\
        |[draw=none,fill=none]| $x:$ \& x \& x \& x \& x \\
                                     \& x \&   \&   \&   \\
    };
}
\only<2>{\fhighlight[color2]{m-2-2}{m-4-5}}
\only<3>{\fhighlight[color3]{m-2-1}{m-4-4}}
\only<2,3>{\repeatMe}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Code 3

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse,etoolbox,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}

\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,1,0}\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{999999}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}

\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {draw=#1,fill=#1!50,rounded corners,line width=2pt}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{color2} m m}{
    \draw[myfillcolor=#1] ([shift={(.1cm,-.1cm)}]#2.north west)rectangle ([shift={(-.1cm,.1cm)}]#3.south east);
}

\def\backgroundtodrawlater{}
\newcommand*{\saveMe}[1]{%
    \ifcsname iph\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname
        \StrCount{\backgroundtodrawlater}{,}[\kommaCount]%
        \StrBefore[\kommaCount]{\backgroundtodrawlater}{,}[\backgroundtodrawlater]
    \fi
    \ifx\backgroundtodrawlater\empty%
        \xappto\backgroundtodrawlater{{#1}/\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}%
    \else%
        \xappto\backgroundtodrawlater{,{#1}/\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname iph\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname{}%
}
\newcommand*{\drawMyBackBoxes}{%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
    \foreach \opt/\name in \backgroundtodrawlater {
        \expandafter\ifx\csname iph\name\endcsname\empty
%           \typeout{opt="\opt", name="\name"}% debug
            \expandafter\path\expandafter[\opt] (\name.south west) rectangle (\name.north east);
            \expandafter\xdef\csname iph\name\endcsname{ }
        \else
            \expandafter\xdef\csname iph\name\endcsname{}
        \fi
    }
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
\tikzset{
    back/.style={
        #1,
        opacity=0,
        save path={#1},
    },
    save path/.code={\saveMe{#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={inner sep=0pt,text centered,opacity=.5,text opacity=1},
    every even row/.style={nodes={
            rectangle,
            back={
                draw,
                fill=color1,
                opacity=.5
            },
            minimum size=0.8cm,
            font=\Large,
            text height=2ex,
            text depth=.25ex,
            text centered,
            text opacity=1,
    }},
    column 10/.style={nodes={text width=1cm}},
    row 1/.style={minimum height=0.5cm},
    row 5/.style={minimum height=0.5cm}
] (m) {
                                                              \& x \& x \&   \&   \\
        |[back={fill=color1!50, draw, opacity=.5, dashed}]| ~ \& x \& x \& x \& x \\
        |[text height=0.2cm]|      ~                                              \\
        |[back={draw=none,fill=none}]| $x:$                   \& x \& x \& x \& x \\
                                                              \& x \&   \&   \&   \\
    };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \only<2>{\fhighlight[color2]{m-2-2}{m-4-5}}
    \only<3>{\fhighlight[color3]{m-2-1}{m-4-4}}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\drawMyBackBoxes
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output 1

[image]

### Output 2

[image]

### Output 3

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a good solution for my example, but i need to do it with several shapes (also with some shapes intersecting more than one node) and think that declaring a new shape each time is too much work. Sorry if this was not clear enough, it is definitely mi fault.

Comment: @antosecret Yes, I added the solution before I could read the comments and added the `beamer` alternative after reading them. Can you add a full `beamer` MWE that shows some examples and how you would achieve them with a “re-drawing node” approach. I think that you will need either re-drawing (could be well done or hidden inside a custom macro) or PGF layers.

Comment: @antosecret I’ve updated my answer with ideas of _re-drawing_ solutions. Though, I’m still waiting for a solution without re-drawing.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: here it is one `:)`. BTW: +1 for your nice solution!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I should have said “re-use” instead of “re-draw”: Your solution is similar to my attemp of solution 1, I wanted to do the drawing of the rectangles inside an `back/append after command`  that uses the `draw`ing and `fill`ing options given to my custom `back` style. But sadly, doing this inside an `pgfonlayer` environment disturbs the localisation of nodes named as `m-2-3`. It would have had the advantage of not having any “a posteriori” (= re-use) commands.