# Forest figure changining between multiple compilations

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, luatex, forest

As it is well known, some [tex projects need to be compiled several times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42401/transparent-node-with-opaque-text) to get things done.

I have this case with the `forest` package where the output is as expected at the first compilation.

[image]

However, I need to run the compilation command more than once as the rest of my slides have references, for instance.

The problem is that the frame became a pretty mess after two or more compilations.
Besides, the figure is fixed after I delete the `.aux` files.

[image]

I'm using `lualatex v1.13`, but the problem remains with other compilers. Does anyone knows what is the problem here?

```
\documentclass[notes,11pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes, arrows, fit, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
  },
  temporal/.code args={<#1>#2#3#4}{%
    \temporal<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}}
  },
  onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
    \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
    treenode/.style = {draw,align=center, inner sep=3pt,
        text centered, font=\sffamily},
    arn_n/.style = {treenode, rectangle},
    arn_x/.style = {treenode},
    gray-arrow/.style = {draw=gray},
    edge=-{Stealth}}
    [$c_{44}$, arn_n,
    [$c_{38}$, arn_n, temporal=<2>{fill=yellow}{fill=yellow!50}{fill=yellow!25}, name=c38,
        [$c_{26}$, arn_n, temporal=<2>{fill=green}{fill=yellow}{fill=yellow!50}, name=c26,
            [$c_{1}$, arn_x, temporal=<2>{}{fill=green}{}, name=c1],
            [$c_{2}$, arn_x, temporal=<2>{}{fill=green}{}, name=c2
              ]
          ],
        [$c_{27}$, arn_n, temporal=<2>{fill=green}{fill=yellow}{fill=yellow!50},
            [$c_{3}$, arn_x,  temporal=<2>{}{fill=green}{}],
            [$c_{4}$, arn_x,  temporal=<2>{}{fill=green}{}
              ]
          ]
      ],
    [$c_{39}$, arn_n,
        [$c_{28}$, arn_n,
            [$c_{5}$, arn_x],
            [$c_{6}$, arn_x]
          ],
        [$c_{29}$, arn_n,
            [$c_{7}$, arn_x],
            [$c_{8}$, arn_x]
          ]
      ]
    ]
    \draw[->, dashed] (c1)  to[out=north west, in=west] (c26);
    \draw[->, dashed] (c2)  to[out=north east, in=east] (c26);
    \draw[->, dashed] (c26) to[out=north, in=west] (c38);
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be related to `remember picture` at least, remove that and it works fine. Beyond that, I have no idea though ..

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. I was unaware that the `remember picture` was useless in my slides (newbie here!)... While it solved my question, I'm curious to know what was affecting it!

Comment: `remeber picture` is `tikz` instruction which need that document should be compiled  at least twice (simplified: at first image coordinates are stored in .aux` file, at second are correct establish on image).

Comment: Normally `forest` cleans away its coordinates etc. (unless you tell it not to). I'm guessing the `tikz` storage is interfering and you're getting multiple things floating around with the same identifiers, but I don't know.